# Did Saint Paul attend the council of Nicaea? Which other councils did he attend?

Tags: church-history, eschatology

My question is exactly who is Saint Paul? When did he live and when did he die? Did he attend the council of Nicaea? Which councils did He attend?

Comment: Welcome to Christianity.SE. For a quick overview, please take the [Site Tour](http://christianity.stackexchange.com/tour). For more on what this site is all about, see: [How we are different than other sites](http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/q/1808/20394). Unfortunately, your question is not one that this site is designed to answer. However, you can find plenty of biographical information about Paul at this Wikipedia page: [Paul the Apostle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paul_the_Apostle). Paul did not attend the Council of Nicea, which happened over two centuries after his death.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The 1st Council of Nicea was held in 325 AD, long after the Apostle Paul was dead (Paul was believed to have been martyred in Rome about 67 AD). The only Council he definitively attended was the Council of Jerusalem (AD 48-50), which is described in Acts 15 and Galatians 2. St. Paul is believed to have been born around 5 AD.

[Paul the Apostle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paul_the_Apostle)